# Data overlapping in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

i really don't know what i am doing wrong here.
i have data in my dictionary that will be displayed if the condition is met:

```
if(incentives[@"extras"][@"1"])
{
    //display image and label
}
```

i am able to display the image and label successfully if one data from the dictionary meets this condition. If i have multiple, lets say 2 datas that met this condition the image and label for data 1 and data 2 overlaps:

[image]

how will i make the food icon and label to display only in cell 1..and the uniform icon and label display on cell 2..

here's what i have so far:

```
        if(incentives[@"food"][@"1"])
        {
            cell2.imgIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-food.png"];

            NSString *strDescription=incentives[@"food"][@"1"];
            NSLog(@"FOOD: %@", strDescription);

            cell2.lblIncentive.text=strDescription;
            cell2.lblIncentive.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            cell2.lblIncentive.numberOfLines=2;
            cell2.lblIncentive.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        }

        if(incentives[@"uniform"][@"1"])
        {
            cell2.imgIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-uniform.png"];

            NSString *strDescription=incentives[@"uniform"][@"1"];
            NSLog(@"UNIFORM: %@", strDescription);

            cell2.lblIncentive.text=strDescription;
            cell2.lblIncentive.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            cell2.lblIncentive.numberOfLines=2;
            cell2.lblIncentive.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        }

        if(incentives[@"commission"][@"1"])
        {
            cell2.imgIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-commission.png"];

            NSString *strDescription=incentives[@"commission"][@"1"];
            NSLog(@"COMMISSION: %@", strDescription);

            cell2.lblIncentive.text=strDescription;
            cell2.lblIncentive.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            cell2.lblIncentive.numberOfLines=2;
            cell2.lblIncentive.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        }

        if(incentives[@"transport"][@"1"])
        {
            cell2.imgIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-transport.png"];

            NSString *strDescription=incentives[@"transport"][@"1"];
            NSLog(@"TRANSPORT: %@", strDescription);

            cell2.lblIncentive.text=strDescription;
            cell2.lblIncentive.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            cell2.lblIncentive.numberOfLines=2;
            cell2.lblIncentive.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        }

        if(incentives[@"extras"][@"1"])
        {
            cell2.imgIncentive.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-extras.png"];

            NSString *strDescription=incentives[@"extras"][@"1"];
            NSLog(@"EXTRAS: %@", strDescription);

            cell2.lblIncentive.text=strDescription;
            cell2.lblIncentive.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            cell2.lblIncentive.numberOfLines=2;
            cell2.lblIncentive.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        }
```

i tried giving separate labels for each incentive and i still get the same result.
any help will be appreciated..
thanks in advance...

UPDATE: i followed the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhJCuDX4GsA..what happens now, is that if i have two data that  meets the criteria, the cell displays the last data that met the criteria..

Comment: Where do you clean up recycled cells?

Comment: @HotLicks, how will i recycle cells? sorry new to using tableview

Comment: Find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a "new" UITableViewCell you are not always creating a new one, you usually are reusing them. so when you add a subview you have to remove it when reusing the cell. and in your case I recommend creating a custom cell like in this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhJCuDX4GsA

Comment: i followed the tutorial and i have another issue..now it doesn't display the other incentive that met the criteria...